# In typo3 news typoscript, how do I set startingpoint to current page ID?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news

In old versions of typo3 this code worked but in latest version v11 it doesn't.The problem is that "this" value defined as "startingpoint" doesn't return current page id anymore.

```
lib.pageNews = USER
lib.pageNews {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = News
  pluginName = Pi1
  vendorName = GeorgRinger
  switchableControllerActions {
    News {
      1 = list
    }
  }

  settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
  settings {
    startingpoint = this
    recursive = 99
    templateLayout = 100
    hidePagination = 0
    #limit = 10
    detailPid = 1075
    list.paginate.itemsPerPage = 20
  }
}
```

What is the "new" way to achieve this?

I tried to call that id in multiple ways like: TSFE:id, lib.currentPageId, TSFE:page|id, TSFE:page|uid, {TSFE:uid}, {TSFE:id}, getTSFE().id, .....

Comment: did you use `startingpoint.data = ...` or `startingpoint.insertData = 1`?

Comment: I used only startingpoint = something / using .data or .insertData giver me error:
strlen(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible by using [`useStdWrap`](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Reference/TypoScript/GeneralSettings.html#confval-useStdWrap).

```
lib.pageNews {
  settings {
    useStdWrap = startingpoint
    startingpoint {
      data = TSFE:id
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/542